# Pandas: Selecting the label (index number )of a Dataframe row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a Dataframe which shows the number of visits per month to different clinics.

I would like to get the index number of the row where "clinic_south" had the highest number of visits (not "month"). In this case it would be the row with index 1.However, I would like to get just the number. How could I do that? Thank you!

[image: dataframe]

Comment: `df['clinic_south'].idxmax()`

Comment: Would that work if the index was a string? E.g. "Row 1"

Comment: sure, it will work